# Duplex printing without cups

Tags: printing, lpd

Hhow do I print duplex with Berkely lpr? (Other lpd suggestions are welcome) It has no options on simplex/duplex modes, but I guess, that they were somehow able to print duplex back then.

Comment: Traditional BSD lpr, or LPRng? On which unix variant? Are you root?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use this command to do so:

```
$ lpr -o duplex
```

You can query the printer's feature set using the `lpoptions` command:

```
$ lpoptions -l
OptionTrays/Number of Input Trays: 1Trays *2Trays
PageSize/Media Size: *Letter Legal Executive A4 A5 A6 Env10 EnvMonarch EnvDL EnvC5 EnvISOB5 EnvISOB6
PageRegion/PageRegion: Letter Legal Executive A4 A5 A6 Env10 EnvMonarch EnvDL EnvC5 EnvISOB5 EnvISOB6
BrMediaType/BrMediaType: *PLAIN THIN THICK THICKERPAPER2 BOND TRANSPARENCIES ENV ENVTHICK ENVTHIN
InputSlot/InputSlot: MPTRAY TRAY1 TRAY2 *AUTO
Duplex/Duplex: DuplexTumble *DuplexNoTumble None
Resolution/Resolution: 300dpi *600dpi 2400x600dpi 1200dpi
TonerSaveMode/Toner Save: *Off On
Sleep/Sleep Time [Min.]: *PrinterDefault 2minutes 10minutes 30minutes
```

#### More examples

You can query a specific printer on a specific host using the `-h` switch to`loptions` along with the `-p` switch.

- Server: print
- Printer: mfc-8480dn

#### Examples

*Basic options*

```
$ lpoptions -h print -p mfc-8480dn
media=Letter sides=two-sided-long-edge finishings=3 copies=1 job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 number-up=1 auth-info-required=none job-sheets=none,none printer-info='Brother MFC-8480DN Laser' printer-is-accepting-jobs=1 printer-is-shared=1 printer-location='downstairs office' printer-make-and-model='Brother MFC8480DN for CUPS' printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1379656065 printer-state-reasons=other printer-type=135188 scaling=100
```

*Printer specific options*

```
$ lpoptions -h print -p mfc-8480dn -l
OptionTrays/Number of Input Trays: 1Trays *2Trays
PageSize/Media Size: *Letter Legal Executive A4 A5 A6 Env10 EnvMonarch EnvDL EnvC5 EnvISOB5 EnvISOB6
PageRegion/PageRegion: Letter Legal Executive A4 A5 A6 Env10 EnvMonarch EnvDL EnvC5 EnvISOB5 EnvISOB6
BrMediaType/BrMediaType: *PLAIN THIN THICK THICKERPAPER2 BOND TRANSPARENCIES ENV ENVTHICK ENVTHIN
InputSlot/InputSlot: MPTRAY TRAY1 TRAY2 *AUTO
Duplex/Duplex: DuplexTumble *DuplexNoTumble None
Resolution/Resolution: 300dpi *600dpi 2400x600dpi 1200dpi
TonerSaveMode/Toner Save: *Off On
Sleep/Sleep Time [Min.]: *PrinterDefault 2minutes 10minutes 30minutes
```

Comment: Please tell me the first line of man lpr. If it is Apple its is from Cups, which I dont want to use.

Comment: Yes it's apple, but I used those same switches on a Solaris system's version of `lpr` as well. This was several years ago (`lpr -o duplex`).

Comment: @slm Solaris uses CUPS these days. `lpoptions` is specific to CUPS.

Comment: @Gilles - this was Solaris 2.6 - 2.9 so I know for a fact it wasn't CUPS! So the ipr -o duplex should still be the way to go.

Comment: @slm Either `lp -o duplex` or `lpr -Z duplex`, I suspect. Neither are available universally on pre-CUPS Solaris, but print filters can provide additional options and `duplex` is a plausible one.

Comment: @Gilles - yes you're correct, it was `lp -o duplex`. I just asked a friend that was still there that had access to the system and he also corrected me.